# Unable to setup Custom Scan using Web Security Centre Google Account Authentication in GCP

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup **Web Security Centre** for my Google AppEngine App.
I tried using *Google* as well as *Non-Google Account* for Authentication where I provided *Username* and *Password* but it errors out saying

**Could not sign in using the provided username and password**

I tried below things:

1. Tried creating a test account *vikash-security@gmail.com* **(in compliant with google naming convention)** in my gmail and using the same for authentication. (this user had same domain name as my company's)
2. Created a test user with different domain name and used it for the authentication.

[image]

Both the above users have access to my Google App.
Both of the way did not work and throws the same error. Can anyone help me out with the same?

Answer (score 0):

Google enforces a real name policy on G+ accounts. Your test account may be blocked from G+ if the name does not look real. at [1]. It will only work if the Google account you provided should have been G+ verified (with proper G+ setup), but still need to retry after the first failed attempt and it eventually will work.
There are few issues related to this and if this is a bug it will be resolved soon.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with all permutation and combinations possible. But unfortunately they seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

I raised this concern with the Google support team and got to know that there was issue from their end and they got this fixed and now my web security custom scan is working with non-google authentication.